# "Длинный волос"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Парикмахеры (да и не только) часто говорят не "волосы", а "волос". Скажите, пожалуйста, это безграмотность или профессиональный жаргон?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Волос" в данном случае имеет собирательное значение и считается разговорным вариантом. Это обозначение растительности на теле человека, в отличие от общего понятия "волос - волосы". Примеры: Волос у меня чёрный, густой.  У бабы волос долог, да ум короток (Посл.). Вероятно, разговорная форма здесь приобретает профессиональную окраску.